# Is it viable to have a file with 700 permissions?

Tags: files, permissions

I have been wondering about the following thing:

Consider Pc A. Pc A has n users. There is a folder with one file per user. There is some sensitive information for each usere there, so you don't want anyone except the owner of the file to be able to read/write from it. (not even the sudo of the other users)

What is the correct approach to achieve that ?
What I have thought of is to set `chmod to 700`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not even the sudo of the other users"? Do you want this file to be unreadable by root, too?

Comment: yes, I want just the user who has created it to be able to edit it.

Comment: Well, no matter what you do you can't prevent a root user from reading or modifying the file. If your users have access to unrestricted sudo, there's nothing you can do to prevent their access.

Comment: Perhaps what you really need is to take away sudo access for the other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a folder with one file per user.

What are the permissions on that folder?  If user Alice can write to that directory, she can `mv bob bob.old` and `echo alice >bob` - she can't read the old `bob` file, or remove it, but she can move it aside, and create a new file named `bob` with contents that she controls.

Assuming that the folder that contains all of these files is writable only by a superuser, though, there's nothing generally wrong with this approach.  And it can be managed even for directories that are writable by multiple users - like `/tmp` - by setting the "sticky bit" on the directory.

And, wait: What do you mean by this?

> you don't want anyone except the owner of the file to be able to read/write from it. (not even the sudo of the other users)

By "the sudo of other users" do you mean that user alice does `sudo cat /path/to/bob`?  There's nothing that you can do to prevent that.  If you let users become root using sudo, you can't prevent them from doing anything - the root user has full permissions to everything.